# How to select pseudo class of a selected pseudo class?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I have a container that consists of rows. Each row has a logo element, and I want the logos backgrounds to be like a chessboard. Here is a sample of one row:

```css
.content-designers .designers > .row  > .logo > span{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}    
.content-designers .designers .row :nth-child(odd) .logo:nth-child(odd){
  background: #f4f4f4;
}    
.content-designers .designers .row :nth-child(odd) .logo:nth-child(even){
  background: #fff;
}
.content-designers .designers .row :nth-child(even) .logo:nth-child(odd){
  background: #fff;
}
.content-designers .designers .row :nth-child(even) .logo:nth-child(even){
  background: #f4f4f4;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-designers">
  <div class="designers">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="logo"> 
        <span></span>
        <img src="">
      </div>
      <div class="logo"> 
        <span></span>
        <img src="">
      </div>
      <div class="logo"> 
        <span></span>
        <img src="">
      </div>
      <div class="logo"> 
        <span></span>
        <img src="">
      </div>       
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The selectors seem to be not working. What is the problem here?

Comment: You have only one logo per row?

Comment: @dfsq no, I have 4 logos per row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to remove the space for `:nth-child` selector and use `display: inline-block` for the `row logo` and not the span. `row logo` by default acts as a block level element and aligns the new rows to a new line.

```css
.content-designers .designers > .row > .logo > span {
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
.content-designers .designers .row .logo {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}
.content-designers .designers .row:nth-child(odd) .logo:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #f4f4f4;
}
.content-designers .designers .row:nth-child(odd) .logo:nth-child(even) {
  background: #fff;
}
.content-designers .designers .row:nth-child(even) .logo:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #fff;
}
.content-designers .designers .row:nth-child(even) .logo:nth-child(even) {
  background: #f4f4f4;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-designers">
  <div class="designers">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="logo">
        <span></span>
        <img src="">
      </div>
      <div class="logo">
        <span></span>
        <img src="">
      </div>
      <div class="logo">
        <span></span>
        <img src="">
      </div>
      <div class="logo">
        <span></span>
        <img src="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="logo">
        <span></span>
        <img src="">
      </div>
      <div class="logo">
        <span></span>
        <img src="">
      </div>
      <div class="logo">
        <span></span>
        <img src="">
      </div>
      <div class="logo">
        <span></span>
        <img src="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="logo">
        <span></span>
        <img src="">
      </div>
      <div class="logo">
        <span></span>
        <img src="">
      </div>
      <div class="logo">
        <span></span>
        <img src="">
      </div>
      <div class="logo">
        <span></span>
        <img src="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="logo">
        <span></span>
        <img src="">
      </div>
      <div class="logo">
        <span></span>
        <img src="">
      </div>
      <div class="logo">
        <span></span>
        <img src="">
      </div>
      <div class="logo">
        <span></span>
        <img src="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am using the span to align the images in the middle of `logo` div, so the span display should be `inline-block` otherwise the image will not be aligned. thanks

Comment: Oh that's right. If that is the case, you should include that too.

Answer (score 3):

You've got spaces in your selectors. Remove the space from `.row :nth-child` in each of your selectors:

```
.content-designers .designers > .row  > .logo > span{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}    
.content-designers .designers .row:nth-child(odd) .logo:nth-child(odd){
  background: #f4f4f4;
}    
.content-designers .designers .row:nth-child(odd) .logo:nth-child(even){
  background: #fff;
}
.content-designers .designers .row:nth-child(even) .logo:nth-child(odd){
  background: #fff;
}
.content-designers .designers .row:nth-child(even) .logo:nth-child(even){
  background: #f4f4f4;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In CSS code, you write `.row :nth-child(even)`, with space. The right syntax is `.row:nth-child(even)` without space.

```css
.content-designers .designers > .row  > .logo > span{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
} 
.content-designers .designers .row:nth-child(odd) .logo:nth-child(odd){
  background: #f4f4f4;
}
.content-designers .designers .row:nth-child(odd) .logo:nth-child(even){
  background: #fff;
}
.content-designers .designers .row:nth-child(even) .logo:nth-child(odd){
  background: #fff;
}
.content-designers .designers .row:nth-child(even) .logo:nth-child(even){
  background: #f4f4f4;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-designers">
  <div class="designers">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="logo">   
        <span></span>
        <img src="">
      </div>
      <div class="logo">    
        <span></span>
        <img src="">
      </div>
      <div class="logo">    
        <span></span>
        <img src="">
      </div>
      <div class="logo">   
        <span></span>
        <img src="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```